# Mapping/trip planning software

Tags: maps, google-maps, openstreetmap, travel

I'm looking for software that would allow me to plan my trips.

It should allow me to:

- add list of points I want to visit and allow:

  - adding notes to the points
  - putting them in folder structure
  - color code markers on the map
  - mark them as visited
  - hide or show selected points without deleting them
- adding points should be possible based on GPS coordinates, just clicking on the map and geocoding
- displaying map with the points
- creating route with all or selected points (preferably with Google Routing)
- have support for Google Maps layers
- have option to add WMS/XYZ layers

Nice to have:

- Free Software/Open Source
- strong preference for it to be Web-based (provided as SaaS or for self-hosting) and if not Linux client (Windows is the least preferred)
- importing points from CSV file

I don't mind if it's paid software, but shouldn't be too expensive (it's for hobby use not business). Preferred one-time cost vs monthly payments.

Comment: How does Google Maps itself not fit your requirements?

Comment: Mainly lacking in ability to add other layers. Also what you can do with points is quite simple (grouping them is not that advanced, it's not that easy to navigate between selected set of points)

Comment: RE layers, does this help at all? https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024933?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Not really. That still operates on user or GM provided data. It doesn't allow you to use third party map like OpenStreetMap.