# What service/software should I use for creating personal maps (for sharing) online?

Tags: maps, mapping

I am looking for a software/service that would allow me to use a base map (either from Google or OSM), and to append my own layers on top of this. I know of the following options:

- Google My Maps: three problems with this: the layer limit is ten, layers above 5Mb do not import, and if a layer has more than a few items in it layer controls disappear off the page so it is very difficult to have good control of what is being displayed;
- uMap: the user interface is *very* problematic (I've not found if there's a way to customize the UI options at the map's opening which might help in getting around this);
- MapQuest: doesn't allow European accounts.

Is there another software/service out there that would get past the main problem expressed with regards to Google (a very low layers and import size limit)?

The following criteria are important:

- different basemap options;
- (virtually) unlimited layers;
- no import size limit;

And the following would be good-to-have:

- custom activated layers on opening the map;
- strong preference for it to be web-based.

I appreciate that my criterion for uMap is very personal; nevertheless, I'd prefer to use something else if there was something better.

Edit: I saw [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/mapping-trip-planning-software), but it doesn't really get anywhere with answers (and it doesn't even list the options I've considered above).